# Enterpriselibrary : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, logging

I have 10 .net consoles starting up on the same time in the same folder. All 10 processes starts by writing startup info (via EnterpriseLibrary) to 10 different log files. The EnterpriseLibrary dll's are released next to the console .exe

Sometimes I get this Exception, when i call Write. The problem is that .net cannot load the EnterpriseLibrary reference. I'm not sure how to deal with this?

> System.TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory'
>   threw an exception. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder,
>   Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The process cannot
>   access the file because it is being
>   used by another process. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80070020) File name:
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder,
>   Version=1.0.51205.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory..cctor()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory.BuildUp[T](IConfigurationSource
>   configurationSource)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterFactory.Create()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(LogEntry
>   log)

Comment: why dont you seperate the log files for those applications??

Comment: That is not the problem. They all write to different log files, but uses the same library